# Vector spaces dimensions

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Suppose vector space $U$ is a subspace of $V$, and $\text{dim}(U) = \text{dim}(V)$. Why does $U = V$?

What theorems make this work?

Comment: This is only true for finite-dimensional spaces.

Comment: This follows from the fact that every $n$-dimensional vector space over a field $\mathbb F$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb F^n$ (the set of $n$-tuples of elements of $\mathbb F$).

Comment: But then you still should show that any $n$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{F}^n$ equals the whole space.

Answer (score 1):

One needs some work to define dimension.

> Let $V$ be a vector space, and $(v_i)_{i \in I}$  be a family of
>   elements from $V$, the following are equivalent :
>
> 1. $(v_i)_{i \in I}$ is a maximal (for inclusion) linearly independent family of elements from $V$
> 2. $(v_i)_{i \in I}$ is minimal (for inclusion) generator family
> 3. $(v_i)_{i \in I}$ is a basis of $V$

Furthermore, we have :
**incomplete basis theorem :**

> Let $V$ be a vector space,
>
> 1. any linearly independent family of elements from $V$ can be extended to a maximal linearly independant family.
> 2. from any generator family, one can extract a basis.

**Corollary and definition**

> Let $V$ be a vector space, all bases of $V$ have the same cardinality.
>   One defines the dimension of $V$ as the cardinality of any basis of
>   $V$.

Both of them rely on **Steinitz exchange principle :**
Let $B$ be a subset of the vector space $V$, for all $x,y\in V$, one has
$$x \in Span(B,y)\setminus Span(B) \Longleftrightarrow y \in Span(Bx) \setminus Span(B)$$

---

**Why does $U=V$?**

As mentioned by Math1000, this holds only if $V$ is finite dimensional (see infinite dimensional counterexample bellow). Assume $dim(V) = n \in \mathbb{N}$. Let $U$ be a subspace of $V$ with $dim(U) = n$.
Let $(u_1,\dots,u_n)$ be a basis of $U$.
$(u_1,\dots,u_n)$ is linearly independent, **we claim that it is a basis of $V$**
if not, one can extend it to a basis of $V$ of size $s>n$, contradicting $dim(V) = n$.
Hence, $U=Span(u_1,\dots,u_n)=V$.

**counterexample if $dim(V)\notin \mathbb{N}$**
Take a field $k$ and consider the polynomial ring $V:=k[X]$, which is a vector space of dimension $|\mathbb{N}|$ since the family $(1,X,X^2,X^3,\dots)$ is a basis. Now take $U:=Span(X,X^2,X^3,\dots)$, one has $dim(U) = |\mathbb{N}| = dim(V)$, but $U \neq V$.